¿Existe una forma de ver las variables estáticas de una clase en modo debug en Eclipse?
Estaba probando hacer un debug de mi aplicación (en Eclipse), una simple de una clase y veo que sale, cuando hago el debug, un recuadro con las variables que se van creando a medida que se ejecuta el programa y los valores que tienen. Al ver en detalle, si mi clase tiene una variable publica estática, no veo esa variable en el listado.
¿Dónde se ven las variables publicas estáticas dentro de una clase en el debug? ¿Hay alguna forma en Eclipse?

Nunca usé eclipse pero te dejo este tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-debugging

Gracias Mateo, en la pagina que compartiste estaba la solución. Gracias.

Se puede configurar la pestaña de Variables para ver las variables Constantes de los Objetos.

Hay que presionar sobre "los 3 puntos"-> Java -> Show Static Variables.

¿Variables constantes o variables estáticas?
